# Where can I get button graphics/decals for car interior (preferably for specific models)?

Tags: paint, audi, interior, restoration

I have seen around a few threads by the business that created [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dux-tj-djNo&feature=plcp). They supply (supplied?) kits to replace the surface of car interior buttons (radio, climate control, etc) that have become worn. I have tried to find where I can buy from them since but hardly anything comes up and that that does (eBay) is dead.

Does anyone know where I can get:

**A. The graphics kit described in the above video?**

Or failing that:

**B. A standard set of decals that I can place over resprayed buttons? (preferably for specific brands of car)**

This is for a 2002 A4 which is suffering the 'peeling rubberised paint' issue. Rubberised paint that matches the interior perfectly is available for spraying the buttons, but I can't find anyone supplying the graphics for after that - whether templates or simple 'stick ons'.

Comment: Probably a stupid question (and it doesn't answer your question, so I've posted it as a comment instead of an answer), but have you tried buying new knobs, buttons, or even the entire dash instead? You can probably get this on Amazon or Craigslist (new or from a wrecked version of your car) cheaper than trying to find some stickers, paint, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try these sites, I have done research on several sites and these two kept coming up and they also have video on youtube to show you how to do it.
http://superiorrestoration.com/categories/graphics
http://www.classicdyeproducts.com/custom_button_graphics
They help me repair my 05 Escalade buttons for my Steering Wheel, A/C Control Unit, and Navigation/Radio and after looking online for replacement buttons these were not only more cost effective but they look good too.
Tell me what you think.

Answer (score 0):

screaming aero graphix make decals for aircraft panels with similar nominclature

Comment: This would be more useful as an answer if you include more information about the company (for example, their website), and declare whether you have any connection or affiliation to them...